# Should this LightDM / Ayatana Design question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I believe I understand why [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166282/why-are-the-login-boxes-on-the-left-and-how-can-i-easily-move-them-to-the-center) was closed--it seemed to be leading to subjective debate. However:

- UI choices are usually made by the [Ayatana Design team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana), and usually have *objectively citable, or researchable* reasons.
- LightDM is actually extremely customizable ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM): "It uses a WebKit backend to draw HTML-based login interfaces."), so it's possible to change the appearance of the login screen without switching to GDM.

The existing answer there was written by two users who later close-voted the question. While answering a question and then voting to close it is appropriate on rare occasion, I think in this case it shows that there's something fundamentally answerable about this question. Future answers could address one or both of the points above.

So I think we should reopen the question.

---

As an alternative to reopening the question, the OP could be asked to open two separate additional questions:

- One about the design decision.
- The other about customizing the login screen.

Comment: I flagged this question earlier (before an answer was submitted, citing it too subjective.  My thinking was that it would open the door for many "why design choices are made". I felt justified when the first answer began "in my opinion..."  There were also 2 elements to the question 1: being subjective (in my opinion) the 2nd element I suspected to be a duplicate of another question.  You guys have been around here a lot longer so I look forward to learning the outcome.

Comment: @StephenMyall Good points, though the question could probably be slightly edited to overcome this, and the existing answer suggests answers are possible. We already consider questions about design decisions constructive [some of the time](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3075/are-questions-about-design-decisions-considered-constructive).

Comment: Fair points all around.  I voted because I didn't think the OP was going to be satisfied.  As some of the comments ran on, it began to look like a vent, not a question.

Comment: A bit off topic but this got me thinking and I actually asked a similar question here on meta moments before this one was submitted. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3743/how-to-answer-is-it-safe-to-install-questions.  the common denominator being "subjective questions".  The same principles given the the answer to that question could be applied here also

Comment: Just for reference, if that question gets to the point of only needing one more to re-open ping me in chat, and I'll vote to reopen.  I just didn't think it was constructive.

Comment: meh, it's a dupe anyway, http://askubuntu.com/questions/73188/how-do-i-move-the-login-dialog-in-lightdm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This appears to have been resolved.

This was reopened (3 user votes + moderator) and the original answer is accepted.

*That does not necessarily speak to the general issue of whether or not questions like this can be on-topic. While my argument was that they generally are, I don't think we have a widely applicable consensus here.*